# Doing survey without limit

Tags: windows-10

I'm also doing surveys once per a day but i'm starting survey with another  browser or incognito window of same browser, it again works for me .
How the website recognize my browser please help me. I am using windows 10 in my pc

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to take paid surveys repeatedly to get more money?

Answer (score 1):

If it works in incognito mode or another browser the survey is most likely using a cookie to track whether the browser has visited that site before.  When using another browser a new cookie would be used, and, of-course, incognito mode does what it does because it does not pass cookies from the main browser.